# Shortest path between every pair of nodes in an /Or graph?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity, computational-mathematics

I am dealing with a weighted directed graphs(uniquely non-negative weighted) that consist of two types of  node, "OR" nodes and "AND" nodes. I want to find the shortest path (with minimal weight) between every pair of vertices

"OR" nodes are regular nodes: they can be visited if at least one of their parents has been visited first. "AND" nodes have a constraint: all their parents must have been visited first.

Could we use (After some changement ...) Floyd or Dijkstra to calculate the shortest path between every pair of nodes?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think this problem instance is similar to game tree evaluation. There is a good randomized algorithm for this problem

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I don't know this algorithm, I will do a little research about it.

Answer (score 0):

The [Travelling Salesman problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TravelingSalesmanProblem.html) can be polynomially reduced to your problem, therefore this problem is NP-hard and has no polynomial solution if $\mathrm P \ne \mathrm{NP}$.

Comment: and what about AO*

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: By searching the net, I found that the algorithm AO * calculates the shortest path in an AND/OR graph.

Comment: Is it polynomial?